# Increase zoom speed when using GoJS

Tags: javascript, gojs

I did some research on this topic here, on the GoJS documentation site, etc., but I am not able to find anything coming even near to what I want.

Here's the thing: I have a diagram written in GoJS. As the data behind it is *fairly* big, it happens to be *fairly* large. So I was wondering if there was any possibility to increase the zoom speed built into GoJS, so that with one scrollstep more scale was added.

What i tried until now is doubling the

```
scrollHorizontalLineChange:
scrollVerticalLineChange:
```

both to 32.
No difference to before so far. Or is there any of the many tools GoJS has, to allow me this sweet increase when needed?

Theoretically, it is possible to use the `"ViewportBoundsChanged"` event to change the zoom factor when it's triggered. But would this be a good solution?

Thanks in advance.

Oh and if any additional details are needed, I will be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **CommandHandler.zoomFactor**, http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/CommandHandler.html#zoomFactor :

```
$(go.Diagram, ...,
  { "commandHandler.zoomFactor": 1.2 },
  ...)
```

The **ToolManager** handles mouse events when no specific **Tool** is running, and it calls **Tool.standardMouseWheel**, which calls **CommandHandler.increaseZoom** or **CommandHandler.decreaseZoom** as appropriate.

By the way, **Diagram.scrollVerticalLineChange** controls how far the diagram is scrolled when you click on the scrollbar's up button or down button.  Or when you call http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#scroll

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much.